# Tricky issue with accessing the data of a (complex) variable, defined as pointer (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda

This is what I assume to know: When printing the variable "i" in the console, the command "std::cout << i" is usually used. If "i" refers to a pointer, I do "std::cout << *i". So far so good.

But in the (classical CUDA FFT) C++ example below, this doesn't work and I don't know why. Here's the code snippet (I don't want to post the entire code for clarity):

```
cufftExecR2C(fftPlanFwd, (cufftReal *)d_PaddedData, (cufftComplex *)d_DataSpectrum);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    std::cout << (cufftComplex*)d_DataSpectrum << '\n';
}
```

"cufftExecR2C" is the 'real to complex' command to do a Fourier transform of numbers 0 to 8 in the variable "d_PaddedData" to the variable "d_DataSpectrum", which has complex numbers. I think these are pointers.

I want to check whether the rest of the code works as intended and print out the variable. Problem: I get this 9 times: "000000070CE00C00" printed in the console, which seems to me the address and not the data of the variable?

Instead of (cufftComplex*)d_DataSpectrum, I tried the following combinations: "*d_DataSpectrum", "d_DataSpectrum", "*d_DataSpectrum[0]", "d_DataSpectrum[0]". The latter two are in probable case the complex variable is stored in a two column array. Only "d_DataSpectrum" can be compiled successfully but also gives me 000000070CE00C00.

I would like to know if I miss any tricks to get the data of that pointer?

---

Edit:

Declarations

```
fComplex *d_DataSpectrum;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_DataSpectrum,   fftH * (fftW / 2 + 1) * sizeof(fComplex))
```

Both lines compile but cause the .exe to crash when calling at exactly that point:

```
    std::cout << "The Original data is " << d_PaddedData[i] << '\n';
    std::cout << "The FFT'd data is" << ((cufftComplex*)d_DataSpectrum)[i].x << '\n'; //crash even with added 'd_DataSpectrum)[i].y' as recommended
```

---

Edit2:

After editing it with a "&" to:

```
    std::cout << "The Original data is " << &d_PaddedData[i] << '\n';
    std::cout << "The FFT'd data is" << &((cufftComplex*)d_DataSpectrum)[i].x << '\n';
```

It runs:

```
The FFT'd data is000000070CE00C10
The Original data is 000000070CE0040C
The FFT'd data is000000070CE00C18
The Original data is 000000070CE00410
The FFT'd data is000000070CE00C20
The Original data is 000000070CE00414
The FFT'd data is000000070CE00C28
```

Why does the "&" work now?

Comment: Only a guess based on the CUDA documentation and some assumptions about your code, but I would try `std::cout << ((cufftComplex*)d_DataSpectrum)[i].x << ' ' << ((cufftComplex*)d_DataSpectrum)[i].y << '\n';`

Comment: It would help to know how `d_DataSpectrum` is declared.

Comment: Thanks, you both are gold. I have added declarations.

Comment: Well a crash is a completely different issue. You have some bug in your code, I'm afraid I have no experience with CUDA so I have no idea what it is.

Comment: I would imagine the crash is caused by the confusion beween `fComplex` and `cufftComplex`. Your code can't seem to make up it's mind which of those two types you really want. You can't just mix and match different types.

Comment: Thanks. The code runs find when I comment the both std::cout lines.

Comment: Can you explain why you are declaring a variable and allocating its memory as one type `fComplex` but then trying to use it as a different type `cufftComplex`? That's the area where the problem is.

Comment: Don't know. Its done so by NVDIA. I added an & in front of it and it runs lol

Comment: `it runs`, well I think the point is that it doesn't. Sorry this is outside of my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which seems to me the address and not the data of the variable?

Yes, that's an address, most likely the (starting) address of your real or complex array d_DataSpectrum (please provide the declaration!). You are not dereferencing here, you simply try to cast to a pointer of cufftComplex. Keep in mind, that you want to print out a complex value, not a single default printable one like float or double!

cufftComplex is (commonly) defined this way:

```
typedef cuComplex cufftComplex;
```

So, under the premise, that your initial array d_DataSpectrum is 'compatible' to cuComplex, you should be able to print your complex value via the way john mentioned in the comments (separated access to real and complex portion):

```
std::cout << ((cufftComplex*)d_DataSpectrum)[i].x << ' ' << ((cufftComplex*)d_DataSpectrum)[i].y << '\n';
```

The reason why you observe a crash:

```
fComplex *d_DataSpectrum;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_DataSpectrum,   fftH * (fftW / 2 + 1) * sizeof(fComplex))
```

This is allocating a device-side memory buffer. For a proper print-out, you have to transfer it back to the host first via cudaMemcpy with cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost to a valid allocated host-side buffer. Even if it's a question too, for the general scheme very similar to your one, see

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cufft-cufftplan1d-and-cufftexecr2c-issues/43811

A general minimal example for host vs device array usage and printing values:

https://gist.github.com/dpiponi/1502434